# What to call information related to a film?

Tags: word-choice

What is called a film's info such as year, director, country, actors, actresses, language, length... all the info related to it.

I don't want to say metadata or credits. Any other words?

EDIT:
I want to find film equivalent of masthead (used in print)

Answer (score 4):

That's not "metadata", it's just "data".

Edit: the approximate equivalent in film of a print publication's masthead is, I believe, the "billing block"; that's what appears at the bottom of a movie poster and on the back of the DVD label, with director info, main actors, run length, etc.

Comment: calling it data is not descriptive at all, and not specific to film

Comment: This answer is also not correct. Most data are metadata. In particular, data that refers to other data are definitely metadata. The only way it could be "just data" in this case is if a film were not data. A film is data.

Comment: I disagree.  A film is an object.  Information about the film is data: the actors, the producers, the length, are all data about the film.  The fact that the year is a number between 1880 and 2012 is metadata.  The fact that the name of the producer is stored in a field named "Producer" which is 50 characters long is metadata.

Comment: I also think that film is a data. But in any case, calling metadata or data doesn't answer my question, please also see the edit.

Comment: I already edited in an answer to your edit.  :-)

Comment: :-) thanks, billing block is the closest one I think but it seems that it doesn't cover year, language, country or other similar data. From wikipedia: "Billing is a performing arts term used in referring to the order and other aspects of how credits are presented for plays, films, television, or other creative works. Information given in billing usually consists of the companies, actors, directors, producers, and other crew members."